# Scrapy returning addiitonal spaces in my .csv?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping to .csv and I'm getting many extra spaces in the .csv file that are not in the actual web page. I'm able to remove tabs and line breaks using `.replace()` but the spaces don't get removed using `.replace()`.   Even if there was something unusual in the formatting of the web page, it should get removed by the `.replace()`.  What am I missing?

```py
import re
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class DhqSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'dhq1'
    allowed_domains = ['digitalhumanities.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/index.html']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'index.html')), 
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = 'vol'), callback='parse_article'),        
        )

    def parse_article(self, response):
        yield { 
            'title' : response.css('h1.articleTitle::text').get().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\s+', ' '),
            'author1' : response.css('div.author a::text').getall(),
            'year' : response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[0].get(),
            'volume' : response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[1].get(),
            'xmllink' : response.urljoin(response.xpath('(//div[@class="toolbar"]/a[contains(@href, ".xml")]/@href)[1]').get()),            
        }
```

Piece of the csv.
https://pastebin.com/7GvZT3b9

Link to one of the pages that's included in the .csv.
http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/000629/000629.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [normalize-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space).

Either replace the css selectors with xpath selectors, or remove the `::text` from the css selector and use xpath with `normalize-space` after the css selector, as shown in the example.

Example:

```py
import scrapy
import unidecode  # to remove "\xa0" from the strings


class DhqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dhq1'
    allowed_domains = ['digitalhumanities.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/000629/000629.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            'title': response.css('h1.articleTitle').xpath('normalize-space(text())').get(default='').strip(),
            'author1': response.css('div.author a').xpath('normalize-space(text())').getall(),
            'year': unidecode.unidecode(response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[0].get()),
            'volume': unidecode.unidecode(response.css('div#pubInfo::text')[1].get()),
            'xmllink': response.urljoin(response.xpath('(//div[@class="toolbar"]/a[contains(@href, ".xml")]/@href)[1]').get()),
        }
        item['author1'] = [unidecode.unidecode(i) for i in item['author1']]
        yield item
```

Output:

```py
{'title': 'Ethical and Effective Visualization of Knowledge Networks', 'author1': ['Chelsea Canon', 'canon_at_nevada_dot_unr_dot_edu', ' https://orcid.org/0000-0002-0431-343X', 'Douglas Boyle', 'douglasb_at_unr_dot_edu', ' https://orcid.org/0000-0002-3301-3997', 'K. J. Hepworth', 'katherine_dot_hepworth_at_unisa_dot_edu_dot_au', ' https://orcid.org/0000-0003-1059-567X'], 'year': '2022', 'volume': 'Volume 16 Number 3', 'xmllink': 'http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/000629.xml'}
```

Comment: Righteous.  I did not know about ```normalize-space``` so many parts of my life are now easier.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages often have a special type of space, called a non-breaking space, represented in HTML vi &nbsp or   .
Once you know the pattern, you can then replace with your standard Python `replace()` call.

Comment: On line 40 of the page source is the title.  The extras spaces in the title csv are coming from that line break in the source.

view-source:http://www.digitalhumanities.org/dhq/vol/16/3/000629/000629.html